# Eclipse - Linked package?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible in Eclipse to use a package that is not in the project folder, without copying it to the project folder? I want Eclipse to use everytime the newest files from a specifig folder.

For example:

```
PACKAGE A
-----------------------------
src
   package
      Client
          Client.java

PACKAGE B
-----------------------------
src
   package
      Gui
          Gui.java
```

Now, I want to use package.Client.Client from package.Gui.Gui, without making a copy of PACKAGE A inside of PACKAGE B. I just want to link to it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `File -> New -> Folder` and activate the `Advanced`-Button to link to a folder.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. You have 2 options:

**1. "Add External Class Folder" containg binaries (.class) files**
[image]

**2. "Link Source" folder**
[image]

Comment: I linked a package(folder) from another proyect , But then eclipse complains the package isnt correct, what now?

Comment: @centenond: too generic your question is. You should create a new question and provide some more details. E.g. what is your definition of package :-)