# How to share source folders across projects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

There have been already several similar questions asked, yet I have not found a quite satisfactory and working solution. In the local file system, I have two Eclipse projects whose structures are alike, and I want some packages to be shared across them. 
And:  
 - I don't want to have multiple copies of source files due to the obvious reasons; 
 - I don't like very much the idea of adding one project to the build path of the other project, because it would require to hold both of them open all the time and may lead to a mess and unintentional changes in the other project that would be difficult to find and fix afterwards; 
 - I would not like to take off the common packages into a third project, I want the projects to be fully self-contained; 
 - the attempts to link folders with source files from one project as virtual folders to the other project leads to impossibility to assign them the right package names (such folders don't form packages and compiler claims that `The declared package "com.example.package" does not match the expected package ""`) 
What is the right way to to manage the task?

Comment: The right way of managing this task is: *"detach the common packages into a third project"*. Seriously. I cannot imagine any good reason for what you are trying to do. The fact that you have not found any way of doing this supports my argument. People don't do this, because it is not a good idea.

Comment: You have several good options to "share" source, packages and/or entire projects in Eclipse.  For example: [Eclipse - Linked package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034560/eclipse-linked-package)

Comment: @Gergely Bacso - Yes, you are right. After considering various aspects of the situation, I eventually followed your suggestion, though I have found a way to link the sources from another project.

Comment: @Gergely Bacso The reason for my attempts to do so was that the two projects I mentioned are actually two different versions of the same project. Some packages should stay unchanged while some others must be restructured, and the old version should stay alive (maintainable) while I work on the new version. I was going to make a new folders for the rewritten packages and leave the others in their old places.

Comment: This looks like a typical refactoring task. For these it is a very good approach to identify and separate the part that you do not intend to change. That normally goes into a separate project. The remaining part is normally branched, the original branch containing the old implementation, while you do the refactoring on a separate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I have found acceptable is to link one project to another as a linked source folder (Project properties -> Java build path -> Source tab -> Link source). The linked folder location should be the source root of the linked project (`...\project1\src\` or `...\project1\`, depending on the linked project settings), where 'com', 'org' etc live; the folder name may be whatever you like.   
In my case I needed to partially reproduce the package structure of the old (linked) project and replace some of the old packages with new packages (located in the current project) with the same names. To do so, one should choose the option `Update exclusion filters in other source folders to solve nesting`. Configuring the filters is not necessary at this stage (and it would not be too convenient now - you would need to write their texts manually), so after adding the linked source you may just press `OK`.  
If you need to exclude some of the packages of the linked source set (I needed in my case) you should configure `Inclusion / Exclusion filters`.   
  
[image]

Now you can point the folders and files of the linked source that you need in you current project, and point ones that should be excluded, using the graphical view of the linked source folder tree (use the `Add Multiple` buttons).